# Wrap a jquery function and return a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

You can I wrap this code so that when a call a function returns the variable contianing the json object?

Example:

```
   function GetNewSomething() {
        var newtb = 0;
        $.get("/something/new",
                function (data) {
                    newtb = data;
                }
                );
        return newtb; // as of now this always returns undefined...
    }
```

Tried this way, but only return undefined..

Thanks in advance guys!

regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. Ajax calls are asynchronous. You have to pass a callback to your function:

```
function GetNewSomething(cb) {
    $.get("/something/new", cb);
}
```

and call it with:

```
GetNewSomething(function(data) {
    // do something with data
});
```

[I wrote something about it](http://thoughts.felix-kling.de/post/2743859538/how-to-return-data-from-an-ajax-call).

Oh and if the response is a JSON string, you might want to use [`.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) which also decodes the response into a JavaScript object.

Comment: 'Don't call us, we call you', love it :)

Answer (score 3):

`.get()` is a wrapper to `$.ajax()`. All AJAX request run **asyncronously** if not explicitly configured otherwise. That in turn means, that your `return newtb;` statement will occur before `$.get()` has finished.

A good way to workaround this issue is to invoke another callback on your own. This could look like:

```
function GetNewSomething(callback) {
    $.get("/something/new",
            function (data) {
                if( typeof callback === 'function' )
                    callback.apply(this, [data]);
            }
            );
}
```

And then call it like

```
GetNewSomething(function(data) {
     // do something with data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$.get` is asyncronous, which is the reason you pass it a function to call when the get request returns.

Answer (score 0):

You could change to make the `$.get` a `$.ajax` and make it syncronous since `$.get` is just a wrapper for a `$.ajax`:

```
function GetNewSomething() {
        var newtb = 0;
        $.ajax({url:"/something/new",
                type:"GET",
                async:false,
                success: function (data) {
                    newtb = data;
                }
          });
        return newtb; 
    }
```

Comment: Yes, theoretically possible, but in most cases a bad idea. Depending on how long it takes to get the answer, this kills all performance and usability.

Comment: Unless you know what your doing avoid `async: false`

Comment: @Felix Kling - I agree and your way is the appropriate way to do it in this scenario. I was just supplying another way that it could be done.  Also, depending if this call is the only processing that is being done, it will seem like processing is halted until the $.get completes and hits the callback. Again it depends on the scenario.

Comment: @Raynos- I agree, but it is something people should also understand that they could use, but only in the right circumstances.

Comment: @amurra: You are right, it depends on the scenario and this is a perfectly valid answer. But I would include the possible drawbacks it has. Otherwise, less experienced developers might just take this, apply it everywhere and are wondering why their stuff, browser, etc. is sooooo slow ;)